# Transforming increments $dx$, $dy$ in Cartesian to Polar coordinate system

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I am trying to gain a better intuition for conversion from Cartesian to polar coordinates during integration. I understand from other readings that the change of variables from Cartesian to polar coordinates requires the transform

$$
dxdy = \frac{dxdy}{drd\theta} drd\theta 
$$
where $\frac{dxdy}{drd\theta}$ is the determinant of the Jacobian, and is required to scale the area between Cartesian and polar space.

To build further intuition I have been playing around with how increments in $x$, $y$ lead to increments in $r, \theta$. From these changes $dr, d\theta$ I want to check the change in area in polar coordinates. However, I can't quite get the example below to work out.

Start with a vector in Cartesian coordinates at $(1, 1)$ and increment the $x$ component $dx=2$ and the $y$ component $dy=1$, with the resulting vector $(3, 2)$. In polar coordinates, the starting vector is $(\sqrt{2}; \frac{\pi}{4})$

Now I would like to translate this increment $dx$ and $dy$ to polar coordinates.

$$
dr = \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} dy
$$

$$
d\theta = \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} dy
$$

$$
r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, \ \theta = \arctan{\frac{y}{x}}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial y} = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} = \frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} = \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}  
$$

$$
dr = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot 2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot 1 = \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

$$
d\theta = \frac{-1}{2} \cdot 2 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 = \frac{-1}{2}
$$

where $x=1$ and $y=1$ used as the initial coordinates. But, the polar coordinates $(\sqrt{2} + \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}; \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{1}{2})$ is not $(3, 2)$ in Cartesian coordinates.

Is this because $dx$, $dy$ should not be used in this way and are only to be considered increments meaningful or accurate as their limit goes to zero? Or maybe my conceptualisation is incorrect elsewhere.

Comment: You can find explanations of the change of variables *determinant* numerous times on this site. You have to think about areas of parallelograms, not multiplications of scalar quantities.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that the calculation of area that works in Cartesian coordinates does not make sense in polar coordinates, and the wedge product should be used. But, my question is regarding first looking at the components $dr$, $d\theta$ separately, which I have not found in other questions. Then, I would like to see how the area traced by $dr$, $d\theta$ in polar coordinates looks for myself and check against the wedge product method of $dr\wedge d\theta$

Comment: Your choices of $dx,\,dy$ aren't infinitesimal, so your estimated changes in $r,\,\theta$ are only approximations. Indeed, they're very bad ones, because your choices are so large.